# Xcode 10 - Turn off Retina display of simulator, or set screen scale to 1

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, retina

I would like to have a window scale of 1 (no retina display), on the simulator for example.

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].scale
```

In other words, this should return 1.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to select a simulated device that has a scale of 1. This includes the iPad 2 and the original iPad, the original iPhone, iPhone 3G and 3GS, and the first three iPod touches. All other iOS devices have a scale of 2 or 3.

Of those, the iPad 2 supported up through iOS 9.3.5 which you can still support in an iOS app with Xcode 10. So set your app's Deployment Target to iOS 9.3 or earlier and run it with the iPad 2 simulator.